# Update post meta is slow while saving post

Tags: wp-update-post

Post saving took much time.
I have action to save custom metas using update_post_meta

```
add_action( 'save_post_property', 'propertys_save' );
function propertys_save($id) {
    foreach($_POST['meta'] as $k => $v) {
        $time_start = microtime(true);
        update_post_meta($id,$k,$v);
        echo microtime(true) - $time_start
    }
}
```

and i get this average timing:

```
0.16451787948608
```

And if i call `update_post_meta` anywhere in another place (for example admin-ajax.php?action=123) it will take:

```
0.00014281272888184s
```

It's 1000 times faster...
Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: No they don't? You're printing times since the start of the update sequence not the times for each individual update. With a few exceptions the differences between each number is 0.033, so they're all taking the same amount of time.

Comment: I don't know of a 'bulk update post meta' function but it would be possible to write one that combines these all into a single database round trip by combining the SQL. However it's only 2/3rds of a second, so that's not too bad is it? How often do you save posts?

Comment: @Rup, sorry, my fault, updated question =)